# PHP loads module, but Apache Start Says No - LDAP

Tags: php, apache

I have the following downloaded on my machine

apache2.2.21 zip from apachelounge

php 5.3.8 thread safe zip from php.net

Windows 7

I've unzipped them both to some path on my computer. Let's say its called $HOME.

So I have $HOME/apach2 and $HOME/php.

I've successfully gotten the phpinfo() page to display and even installed the xdebug extension for debugging purposes in netbeans.

My problem is the following :

I uncommented 'extension=php_ldap.dll' in the php.ini because I need ldap connectivity.

I'll start apache and the monitor says that apache is running. I then navigate to my index.php but an error occurs saying that ldap_connect doesn't exist.

When I type if 'php --rf ldap_connect' into the command line, I get the function prototype no problem.

I even have a php script written that will use the ldap extension to do ldap search.

```
$conn = ldap_connect( 'ldap://myhostsomewhere', 389 );

ldap_set_option( $conn, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3 );

ldap_bind( $conn, 'cn=admin,dc=emc,dc=com', 'secret' );


$rs = ldap_search( $conn, 'cn=jerry,ou=people,dc=example,dc=com', '(cn=jerry)');


$stuff = ldap_get_entries( $conn, $rs );


var_dump( $stuff );
```

The code above will return an array with all the results and I get NO errors.

When I check the Apache error log however, I get the following error,

PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:/Users/jerry/Documents/myprogs/php/ext/php_ldap.dll' - The specified module could not be found.\r\n in Unknown on line 0.

I've double checked and triple checked and the directory is there and all but it isn't loading when apache tries to run php. BUT it loads fine when I run PHP through the command line.

I've looked at the phpinfo() and apache is loading the correct php.ini file as well.

I have NO clue what is going one.

The weird part is that usually a php error like that might cause apache to stop and cause some sort of fault. It's a PHP Warning though, and apache starts up just fine but it complains when I try to call ldap_connect.

Anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I solved it.

I think that I must've switched the value of something in the php.ini file. I took the windows php installer, ran it and let it override the existing php.ini file.

After that, I took the zipped version of php and dropped it in to replace the windows installer version but I saved the php.ini file. After that it worked fine, no issues.